# blank window with XDMCP between linux and unix

Tags: debian, x11, remote-desktop, xdmcp, tru64

I have a Digital Unix 4.0 emulation running without a display (FreeAXP). I have an X app (Open Genera 2) on this host that I would like to use.

I managed to configure both Unix and Linux and I can do X login from Linux (Debian 11 at the moment) to Unix. Both X and CDE environments seem to be working fine.

However, when I run the mentioned application, I only see a (white) blank window without any contents.

I tried a different X server (on Windows) and also not using XDM but setting display explicitly and running the program from telnet, but no change.

I can see the network traffic (on 6000/tcp) with tcpdump on Unix.

I am considering using Xvfb on Unix to see if it works locally and also proxy/debug X messages on Linux, but I dont see why it would be different.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Sniff traffic using something like https://wiki.wireshark.org/X11 and read output carefully. I believe there is a protocol mismatch between modern Xorg and 27 years old Unix.

Comment: I found the issue. Open Genera has something regarding to xlib that has to be modified, I forgot about that thinking I am running it on Alpha but the X is remote and new so I have to use that fix as well, and now it looks OK.